# How to close color box in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using colorbox. I want open css-lightbox after close the colorbox. So my css-lightbox is ready and working fine. But when I close colorbox then I have error in console.

JavaScript code is:

```
 $(".login_message").click(function(){
     $(".login_alert").hide();
     $(".emailNot").hide();
     $(".login_ok").hide();

     openforgotpw(); // open css-lightbox

     jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();   /* close the colorbox */

 });
```

Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined
```

Please help to close the colorbox. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the error is of the form Cannot call method 'X' of undefined, it means that whatever object you are attempting to call X from does not exist.

In your case, it appears as though 'close' is undefined. The easiest way to resolve this involves:

Make sure that none of your code executes until the browser is ready. The best way to do this is to wrap all of your code within a .onReady() call.

Comment: Now I have remove jquery.js file and colorbox is close on click. but problem is that css-lightbox is also close. i want close only colorbox not css-lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();
```

or you can try like this also

```
$(window).colorbox.close();
```

Comment: Now I have remove jquery.js file and colorbox is close on click. but problem is that css-lightbox is also close. i want close only colorbox not css-lightbox.